# data load in extjs panel from button ajax responce

Tags: php, ajax, html, extjs4

i am new to extjs 4 and i am struck at when i am click button then ajax request get data from `url` and that `ajax` `responce` `data` will load in `panel`
below code is buttion code

```
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        flex:1,
                                        height: 30,
                                        text : 'GEography',
                                          handler:function() {
                                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                    url: 'charts/states.php',
                                                    method: 'GET',
                                                    scripts:true,
                                                    success: function (response) {
                                                        Ext.get('ajaxpanel').dom.innerHTML = response.responseText;
                                                        }
                                                                        });
                                                }
                                    },{
```

and below code is panel code

```
  var ajaxForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'ajaxpanel',
        id:'ajaxpanel',
        frame: true,
        bodyPadding: 5,


        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign: 'left',
            msgTarget: 'side'
        },

        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },

        items: []
        });
```

so please help me in above problem 
main aim is that's url dat load in ajaxpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below answer for above question 
for ajax loading

```
                                             listeners: {
                                                click: function(){

                                                        Ext.get('ajaxpanel').load({url:'ur url here',scripts:true});

                                                        }
                                                }
```

Comment: That is a poor solution. If you're looking to load components dynamically, look at this example, specifically, the 3rd panel: http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/component-loader/component-loader.html